# Passenger: Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, rake, bundle, passenger

I have a rails app running on debian with apache2 + passenger but I get this message from passenger:

```
Error message:
    Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

The strange thing is that rake-10.0.4 seems to be already installed:

```
> bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * ...
  * rake (10.0.4)
  * ...
```

Do someone have any idea where does that come from ? Thanks !

Comment: Do you use rvm or rbenv or something?

Comment: Have a look at https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/ and google for passenger and rvm, this is a path / environment issue. There are also plenty of questions about this exact topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I've been struggling with this problem - I just posted my solution at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17088480/1578861

It sounds like your passenger configuration is pointing to a different version of ruby to the one you are using to run your bundler

Check which ruby version your rvm is using:

```
    $ rvm env --path
```

Find your `passenger.conf` and update `PassengerRuby` - you can do this using a config utility provided by passenger

```
   passenger-config --ruby-command
```

Make sure use use the fully qualified path before `passenger-config` (to avoid my [frustrating late night mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17088686/1578861))

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks for this!